# Augmented Least Square Solution

Tags: optimization, least-squares

Assume $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \ m > n$ is full rank, and the linear system $Ax = b$ is inconsistent. The solution to $\min_x \|Ax-b\|^2$ is given by the least-square, $A^+b.$

Similarly, assume $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \ m > n$ is full rank, and the linear system $Cx = d$ is inconsistent. The solution to $\min_x \|Cx-d\|^2$ is given by the least-square, $C^+d.$

Now consider $\min_x \|Ax-b\|^2 + \|Cx-d\|^2.$ The solution to this problem is the least-square solution  $E^+f,$ where $E$ and $f$ corresponds to the augmented linear system.

Is there a closed-form solution for $E^+f$ as a function (among others) of $C^+d$ and $A^+b$?

Similarly, can we relate the residuals?

Comment: Seems unlikely, the solution to the latter satisfies $(A^TA+C^TC) x = A^Tb+C^Td$.

Comment: @amsmath: Yes, thanks for catching that

Comment: @copper.hat, I  think you should post it as a solution so it will be marked.

Comment: @Royi: Well, it it not an answer, so probably a comment is best.

Comment: Why not? With a little more formalization and it is.

Comment: @copper.hat Your solution is correct. My (first) question is equivalent to whether we can find a relation between the augmented pseudo-inverse and the original pseudo-inverses.  For example ,in the book Generalized Inverses and its application (Greville and Ben-Israel), this is answered in the context of common solutions of linear systems (augmented linear system vs original ones)